# I get Error: syntax error: inserting ELSE ID when compiling my SML code and I don't know why

Tags: sml

I am attending a Coursera class, and I am trying to do my homeworks.

We have to write an SML program that takes a list of cards (caracterised by their suit and rank) and returns true if they all have the same color and false otherwise.

Here is my code (i can't figure why its false, but i am quit a noob in programming):

```
datatype suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int 
type card = suit * rank

datatype color = Red | Black
datatype move = Discard of card | Draw 


fun card_color (c) = case c of
(Hearts,_) => Red
|(Diamonds,_)  => Red
|(_,_) => Black


fun all_same_color (cs) = case cs of
    [] => false
    |x::[] => true 
|x::y::[] =>  if card_color (x) = card_color (y) then true
|x::y::xs => if card_color(x)=card_color(y) then all_same_color(xs)
                        else false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an `if ... then ...` without an `else ...` case.

You attempt to do this here:

```
|x::y::[] =>  if card_color (x) = card_color (y) then true
```

Remember, `if ... then ... else ...` is an expression, and thus needs a value whether or not the condition is true or false.

In addition, if you get an `if-then-else`, where either the `then` or `else` parts are `true` or `false` directly, you can write it more succinctly. For instance,

```
if card_color(x)=card_color(y) then all_same_color(xs) else false
```

is the same as saying

```
card_color x = card_color y andalso all_same_color xs
```

Comment: @Sam: Happy to help. Remember to accept an answer by checking the checkmark next to an answer if you find it has solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that language but your last condition is incorrect (I assume is some kind of Haskell):

```
|x::y::xs => if card_color(x)=card_color(y) then all_same_color(xs)
                    else false
```

should be:

```
|x::y::xs => if card_color(x)=card_color(y) then all_same_color(y::xs)
                    else false
```

I don't know if (y::xs) is what I mean, that parameter should be a list with y followed by xs. Using that condition, your third case is redundant, so the last function should be:

```
fun all_same_color (cs) = case cs of
    [] => false
    |x::[] => true 
    |x::y::xs => if card_color(x)=card_color(y) then all_same_color(y::xs)
                    else false
```